# Complete examples of authentication using Laravel Passport in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I can't seem to find complete examples of using Laravel Passport for user authentication (email and password), for a React Native app.

Do you guys have a working example of the complete set up, that is I'd like to have a look at auth controller methods and for example an axios call in the frontend, I'd then be able to cook something up from that starting point into my app.

Thanks in advance and happy coding

Comment: Have you found a solution?